# How to use php code inside a div id?

Tags: php, wordpress, html, title

I'm playing around with some PHP in Wordpress.
I'm trying to give every new post title an unique h1 ID, taken from the post name.

So if posting an post named 'Chapter 1', the title should look like

```
<h1 id="Chapter 1">Chapter 1</h1>
```

the following code isn't doing the magic

```
<h1 id="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: So what does `the_title` look like? What does the output of that PHP look like? Why are you trying to generate invalid HTML (and ID cannot contain a space)?

Comment: Maybe you should add `echo`?

Comment: @Sanja my thoughts exactly.

Comment: you forgot to echo the_title() . common mistake for beginners .

Comment: Note, `id`'s [must not contain whitespace / blanks](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) - so you should consider sanitizing before setting "Chapter 1" or whatever as ID.

Comment: @davidkonrad Got a point there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not echoing inside of `the_title();` but returning you should add an `echo`

```
<h1 id="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>
```

OR

```
<h1 id="<?= get_the_title(); ?>"><?= get_the_title(); ?></h1>
```

-- Change `the_title()` to `get_the_title();`

As suggested in the comments, getting the title for the id may be a bad option, you could strip white space or any character that is not a letter or number:

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', get_the_title());
```

Comment: I would not use the title of a post, because it could contain characters which are not allowed in the ID-tag (e.g. blanks, quotes). You should take - if you have - an ID of the post or a hash of the title or something similar

Comment: In WordPress `the_title()` echoes a string. `get_the_title()` returns it. He is using WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using WordPress, as `the_title` is clearly a WordPress template loop function.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) spaces are not valid characters for an ID value. Most browsers will strip everything after a space in an ID.

I would suggest using [the slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Post_Slug):

`echo basename(get_permalink())`

Answer (score 1):

the correct function to do this is `the_ID();`

eg.:

```
<h1 id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

reference link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID

Answer (score 0):

Define `global $post;` to the top of the page to get the current `post's` array

```
<h1 id="<?php echo 'Chapter'.$post->ID; ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h1>
```

I suggest you to this in the above mentioned way rather than printing the title in `id` attribute,because title may occur too long so your id attribute will be same as title of the post and that a bad practice.